# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module on antd typography in jest

Tags: reactjs, antd, ts-jest

I have a react app that uses antd. I am writing jest test, and I get this error when I run it

[image]

My jest.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
};
```

My babel.config.js is:

```
module.exports = { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] };
```

Tried this but didn't work: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/2081#issuecomment-699558143

Answer (score 0):

Try changhing:

```
import Paragraph from 'atnd/es/Typography/Paragraph'
```

To:

```
import {Typography} from 'antd'

...

const {Paragraph} = Typography
```